# Button VS a-tag

Tags: javascript, html

In our application we use A-tags to create all custom styles elements, such as custom CSS buttons.
We alter the A-tags with our CSS and set **href='javascript:void(0)'**.

The main problem is with Chrome showing the bottom label 'javascript:void(0)' on hover.

Can we just switch all A-tags to button, or is there some major drawback we have consider?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using an anchor tag in the first place if your anchor tag doesn't point to a URL and is being used as a button. That's sort of like wrapping your text in `<b>` tags and making it italic.

Making your HTML semantically correct is a good practice, so no, there are no downsides aside from dealing with browsers' default styles for the `<button>` element.

Comment: +1 - always keep your html semantically correct (in this case, buttons would probably be appropriate) and only THEN start to apply css for good looks.

Comment: You've answered the question, but started out with the opposite. Should have been "Yes, but..."

Comment: I think `<button>` is more semantically correct than `<span>`.

Comment: `or is there some major drawback we have to consider?` - `Probably not.`
always difficult with these kind of "double-questions"..

Comment: What about links that are only meant to call javascript rather than point to a URL?

Comment: @DanielTaiber: Those aren't links.